# How does put() method of LinkedHashMap internally works?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am trying to understand a internal working of linkedhashmap.

So when we call put(map,key) of linkedhashmap. Internally it calls `[createEntry][1]` .

```
 void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
440        HashMap.Entry<K,V> old = table[bucketIndex];
441        Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, old);
442        table[bucketIndex] = e;
443        e.addBefore(header);
444        size++;
445    }
```

Here I am not able to understand the use of old variable.

Why new entry is added before the header. It should be added to the end of linkedhashmap.

Can somebody explain this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why new entry is added before the header.

It is simpler to implement this way.  It is the same for HashMap.  This is the collision linked list, not the one the iterator uses.

> It should be added to the end of linkedhashmap.

Where does it say that?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about insertion of key value in linkedhashmap ? For ex: 1st it finds a bucket using the hash of key. I am not able to understand the next step.

Comment: A hash is derived from the key.  If there is not entry already, it is added.  If there is an entry, `equals(Object)` is called on the key.  If it is not a match a new entry is added to the start of the linked list.

Comment: What is the use of that old keyword in the code. The old entry is over write(line:442)  by new entry.

Comment: I got it , so the old means if there is a already in a bucket? Then new Entry is added and it will point to the old one ?

Comment: @Thinker Correct or `null` if it wasn't set.

Answer (score 1):

### First know how HashMap put() method works:

#### Adding key-value pair to the map using put method:

```java
public V put(K var1, V var2) {  
    return this.putVal(hash(var1), var1, var2, false, true);  
}
```

Here we pass the key - K *var1* and value – V *var2*.

The `put()` method calls the `putVal()` method internally and `putVal()` takes the following arguments.

- `hash(var1)` - hashCode of the key
- *var1* – key
- *var2* – value
- boolean false value
- boolean true value

`putVal()` first checks for the HashMap table and if the table is null or empty then calls the `resize()` method. And the `resize()` method creates a new table for HashMap.

Resize() method call – initially the table is null. So for the first time a new table is created with the default size. If an initial capacity was set using `HashMap(int initialCapacity)` or `HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)` constructor in threshold field then initial capacity is set according to threshold.

Otherwise it picks the default initial capacity for the table size.
Default initial capacity of a HashMap is 16 which is defined using the below HashMap field.

```java
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16
```

In case initial capacity is defined :

```java
int oldThr = threshold; //Threshold is being set in oldThr local field
```

And then depending on the below condition, in case threshold is greater than 0, it is being set as `newCap(new capacity for the table)`

```java
else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold  
    newCap = oldThr;
```

Otherwise using default:

```java
newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;  
newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
```

New table is created using the new capacity :

```java
Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
```

In other cases it checks for the `MAXIMUM_CAPACITY`, if the current capacity is more than `MAXIMUM_CAPACITY` then it resizes the table.

After return to putVal:

Then if the index value `[(n - 1) & hash]`, table bucket is empty, the `newNode()` method is called and a newly create entry node is placed at the calculated index in the HashMap table.

```java
if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)  
    tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
```

Then checks for the hash value index in the hash table if there is no already existing node then it created a new Node which contains the hashCode, Key, Value and next node reference in that hash table bucket. Initially it will be null, when a new node will be added to the same hash index, then a LinkedList will be formed as the new node with the same hashcode index will be appended next to the previously added node in a linked list manner using the next field reference.

**To know more about HashMap go through :**
http://techmastertutorial.in/java-collection-internal-hashmap.html

#### LinkedHashMap put() method:

Adding a key-value pair is same as HashMap, in case of LinkedHash map we are keeping additional details with the help of the before and after references.
Since we add an entry for each key value pair so while adding the entry, updating the before and after references also. A doubly linked-list is formed with the before and after references. Using the before and after pointers we can traverse the entries in the order of insertion.

We can start at the head node ( the first node ) added to the LinkedHashMap and traverse using the after pointer until after is null.

LinkedHashMap Internal Working :
http://techmastertutorial.in/java-collection-internal-linked-hashmap.html